# ERROR : This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I get this ERROR that's preventing me from uploading to the AppStore

```
ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. 

This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. 

All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."
```

- I don't have two xcode versions in my mac
- I checked xcodebuild -sdk -version and I have 12.1 and I checked command line tools path by using "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

Output of xcodebuild -sdk -version:

```
iPhoneOS12.1.sdk - iOS 12.1 (iphoneos12.1)
    SDKVersion: 12.1
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 12.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
    BuildID: ...
    ProductBuildVersion: 16B91
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: iPhone OS
    ProductVersion: 12.1

    iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk - Simulator - iOS 12.1 (iphonesimulator12.1)
    SDKVersion: 12.1
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 12.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
    BuildID: ...
    ProductBuildVersion: 16B91
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: iPhone OS
    ProductVersion: 12.1

    MacOSX10.14.sdk - macOS 10.14 (macosx10.14)
    SDKVersion: 10.14
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 1.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform
    ProductBuildVersion: 18B71
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: Mac OS X
    ProductUserVisibleVersion: 10.14.1
    ProductVersion: 10.14.1

    AppleTVOS12.1.sdk - tvOS 12.1 (appletvos12.1)
    SDKVersion: 12.1
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVOS12.1.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 12.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform
    BuildID: ...
    ProductBuildVersion: 16J602
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: Apple TVOS
    ProductVersion: 12.1

    AppleTVSimulator12.1.sdk - Simulator - tvOS 12.1 (appletvsimulator12.1)
    SDKVersion: 12.1
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator12.1.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 12.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform
    BuildID: ...
    ProductBuildVersion: 16J602
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: Apple TVOS
    ProductVersion: 12.1

    WatchOS5.1.sdk - watchOS 5.1 (watchos5.1)
    SDKVersion: 5.1
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS5.1.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 5.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform
    BuildID: ...
    ProductBuildVersion: 16R591
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: Watch OS
    ProductVersion: 5.1

    WatchSimulator5.1.sdk - Simulator - watchOS 5.1 (watchsimulator5.1)
    SDKVersion: 5.1
    Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator5.1.sdk
    PlatformVersion: 5.1
    PlatformPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform
    BuildID: ...
    ProductBuildVersion: 16R591
    ProductCopyright: 1983-2018 Apple Inc.
    ProductName: Watch OS
    ProductVersion: 5.1

    Xcode 10.1
    Build version 10B61
```

- I have base sdk set to iOS in my build settings
- I use xcode 10.1  (10B61)
- I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode

Any ideas? I can't upload to the AppStore anymore, it's been a week now of searching for a solution, I can't find the solution.

Comment: Update to Xcode 10.2?

Comment: My mac doesen't support it, but a friend of mine has 10.2 and he has the same issue

Comment: Hmm maybe it’s a problem at Apple’s end.

Comment: Is it really an _error_?

Comment: Yes! it is an error, not a warning, and it's preventing the upload to itunesConnect

Comment: What's the outcome on this?

Comment: had to use dosdude1 method to install mojave on my machine, and downloaded Xcode 10.2 and it worked.This appears to be a problem with xcode 10.1

Comment: Wow! Can you give that as an answer and accept it? That’s got to be useful to others.

Comment: Done! hope this saves some time for anyone with a similar issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, in Xcode 10.2 this problem doesen't exist. After trying numerous solutions, the one that did it for me was Installing the 10.2 version of Xcode. I hope this answer can help someone save some time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Xcode 10.1 (For other reasons I can not update to Xcode 10.2 yet). Everything in my project was pointing at SDK 12.1 and I still got the error message when trying to upload to the App Store.

I eventually resolved the issue by removing the "iPhoneOS12.0.sdk" folder from "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs" and leaving the one for "iPhoneOS12.1.sdk". There was no need to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: In my case I had only one folder in that path, and it was the iPhoneOS12.1.sdk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have iOS 12.1 SDK installed:

Open XCode preferences, and go to the "Locations" tab.

Select the appropiate "Command Line Tools" version in that screen. That should help.

Comment: There is only one version there and it is xcode 10B61

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other warnings or errors? [The iOS submission guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/) point out a few more requirements than just the iOS 12.1 SDK, like requiring watchOS 5 if you have a watch app. Make sure there are no issues there:

> Starting March 27, 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store will
>   need to be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, and support the
>   all-screen design of iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd
>   Generation). All watchOS apps will need to support watchOS 5 and Apple
>   Watch Series 4.

An unlikely culprit for that error message, but for good measure, make sure your app includes a 64-bit binary. You can also include a 32-bit binary if you support devices running iOS 10 or earlier, but you **must** provide a 64-bit binary.

If Xcode is still failing to upload, try uploading with the Application Loader. In Xcode, select `File>Open Developer Tool>Application Loader`.

If that still fails *in the same way*, I'd uninstall and reinstall Xcode; it couldn't hurt. You might want to look up how to **really** uninstall all the Xcode bits and then do a clean install.

I've heard rumblings of this issue fixing itself on the Apple backend, but if it's still happening after a week, that seems unlikely.

If all else fails, log into your developer account, go to [the apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/forums) and ask for help. An Apple engineer there may be able to help you set things right.

Comment: There is only the error mentioned, no other warnings. I tried your suggestion uploading using application loader, it gave me the same error. Now I am left with trying to uninstall and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Hey, one other thought, if you haven't already done that. Just to make sure that there's nothing wrong with the selected command line tools path, execute this in the Terminal. Change the path if your Xcode isn't called Xcode.
`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode, and checked the path using your command and still the same error when uploading

Comment: I edited the question adding the output of xcodebuild, please take a look at it to see if there are any anomalies

Comment: That matches what I have here. I haven't tried submitting recently, but I don't see anything wrong with your install. I'd hit up the Apple developer forums next. If you figure anything out, please report it back here for others.

Comment: will do for sure, wouldn't want for anyone to go through this as i did